# ¿Cómo crear una consulta agregada con MongoDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb, pipeline

Intento consultar un base de datos MongoDB con Django

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print("JE SUIS PASSE PAR LA")
        # object_list = list(collection.find({"q0.Results.0.Name": {"$regex": str(query), "$options": "i"}}))
        object_list = list(collection.aggregate([
            {
                "$search":{
                    "autocomplete":{
                        "query": str(query),
                        "path": "name",
                        "fuzzy":{
                              "maxEdits":2,
                        }
                     }
                 }
            }]  
            print('type(object_list): ', type(object_list))
            return object_list
```

Pero no me devuelve nada:

```
[11/Mar/2021 14:36:07] "GET /similar/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3938
JE SUIS PASSE PAR LA
[]
```

Tambien lo intenté en el constructor de etapas del pipeline de agregación en MongoDB Atlas pero no sé como hacerlo:

```
/** 
 * index: the name of the Search index.
 * text: Analyzed search, with required fields of query and path, the analyzed field(s) to search.
 * term: Un-analyzed search.
 * compound: Combines ops.
 * span: Find in text field regions.
 * exists: Test for presence of a field.
 * near: Find near number or date.
 * range: Find in numeric or date range.
 */
{
  index: 'test', # el nombre del mio index
  text: {
    query: 'atelier', # un ejemplo. Tengo un documento cual field name esta atelier.
    path: 'name' # el nombre del field sobre cual quiero indexar
  }
}
```

Comment: El método `aggregate()` debe recibir una lista de `pipelines`, actualmente estás pasando un diccionario, debes pasar el mismo así: `collection.aggregate([ { ... } ])`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio. No hay ningun error ahora pero no me devuelve nada tampoco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé porque no funciona. Entonces he rehecho mi índice en `default` y me inspiré [del tutorial de MarcusSorealis](https://github.com/MarcusSorealheis/Atlas-Search-Python#an-example-search-index-definition):

```
object_list = list(collection.aggregate([
                {
                    '$search': {
                        'index': 'default',
                        'compound': {
                            'must': {
                                'text': {
                                    'query': str(query),
                                    'path': 'name',
                                    'fuzzy': {
                                        'maxEdits': 2
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        ))
```

Y funciona